# Weird render faillure material volume

Tags: rendering, volumetrics

I am just starting with blender and am actually in the middle of my first tutorial from Blender Guru.

I just rendered a scene with a coffee cup with coffee in it, and suddenly dark tiles appear in the render image. After a little research, is seems to come from the material volume, that the coffee material uses.
[image]

If I delete the volume from the material, everything is fine again.
[image]

So it seems like, the CPU, when I follow the tiles, is rendering the tiles darker than the GPU.

My setup:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700x
GPU: AMD Radeon RX7500
RAM: Corsair DDR4 Vengeance LPX 2x8GB 3200
MB: MSI X570 Gaming Edge Wifi

Is this a known problem and is there maybe a easy fix? Disabling the GPU in render settings does solve the problem, but drastically increases the render time.

Hope somebody can help!